# Css Html JavaScript - Navigation Highlight current selected Menu

Tags: php, javascript, html

i think this question is very easy but I don't know if i am right. 
I am an oldschoool html, php coder. 
I want to use this kind of navigation:
http://www.cssportal.com/horizontal-menus/13styles.htm

So far no problem. I got an dynamic php page and i want to use this Menu.
There is no problem without this line in the HTML Part:

```
  <li><a href="" title="" class="current"><span>LINK</span></a></li>
```

The Problem is the class. What is the smartest way to detect which link is now current? 
I would do it in this way. I would write a php script like this pseudo code:

```
if acutaldocument == "link1.html" then echo "class='current' ";
```

But i think this is not the smartest way. Or am I right?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many options...

You can use session cookies, JavaScript, you can pass an id on the end of the url (eg. ?nav=2) or parse the URL and check against it...

All of them work... all of them have there pros and cons... just depends on how your page is set up...

Comment: Parsing with php, like i said? There is no smarter way

Comment: Is it one page and you are changing the content on the page? or are these different pages? If it's the former, which it sounds like... you can use a cookie, some script... or if the url changes/variable passed you can check against/parse it. If it's the latter, then I'd just use a variable before any header information is fired and go from there... just depends on your set up.

Answer (score 1):

Give each page's body tag an ID. Say, you give the About page's body tag the id "about". Give IDs for all your navigation `<li>`s too. Say, you give "about" id to the navigation `<li>`

In your CSS file, do this:

```
body#about li#about {
   // apply differentiating style here...
}
```

You can keep doing that for all other pages also. And only when both the body ID and the `<li>` ID match, the style is applied.

Comment: The problem is, i got only one php page with dynamic content. 
How can i give this page the right body id?

Comment: You can parse the URL. Chuck of the extension and use the file name as an ID?